# How to make custom application display templates in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I am new to liferay.. and am trying to make a custom ADT in liferay. Where would I get documentation to use the variables in the script of custom ADT. How to make a start up? I searched a lot but to no avail..Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the main tutorial of the web page: [Tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-application-display-templates) [Tutorial 2](https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/implementing-application-display-templates)

Here is the API for the methods you need: [API](https://docs.liferay.com/)

And this video can be useful : [Youtube Dev ADT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcpC_8HyGNI)

Good luck in Liferay, is hard to learn

Answer (score 0):

Not much documentation, indeed. James Falkner made a script some time ago to show some info about ADTs and variables. See if it helps. https://web.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/dumping-adt-wcm-template-variables

Comment: thanx for providing link..but i dont think it contains information enough to make  an ADT..